# How to map state variable in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-select

How to onChange with same object in options

```
<Select
      options={this.state.materialunit.map(obj => {return({value: obj.materialunitID, label: obj.unitName + ': ' + obj.materialName})})}
      onChange={e => this.setState({unitPrice: obj.unitPrice })}
/>
```

Comment: you trying to create a SelectBox for each of the  objects in `this.state.materialunit` ? or a single SelectBox with data in `this.state.materialunit` as options ??

Comment: single selectBox with data in material unit as options :/ i think my code is not good so how to onChange with same object?

Comment: Could you provide the version of react-select you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct options for react select, I would suggest to move the logic to a method. So, the code will look like

```
onSelectMaterialUnit(selectedMaterialunit){
  //store selected option in state
  this.setState({selectedMaterialunit})

}
materialUnitOptions(){
  return this.state.materialunit.map(materialUnit => (
    {
      value: materialUnit.materialunitID,
      label: `${materialUnit.unitName}:${materialUnit.materialName}`
    }
   )
}


render(){
  return(

    <Select
       value={this.state.selectedMaterialunit}
       onChange={this.onSelectMaterialUnit}
       options={this.materialUnitOptions()}
     />

 )
}
```

Also, if you want to pass the options directly without mapping label and values, you can set `valueKey` and `labelKey` in react-select v1 and in v2 you can use `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` methods respectively. Hope this will help.
[Documentation here](https://react-select.com/advanced#replacing-builtins)